# Append or Add nested JSON into another JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am using typescript, I have an existing JSON response below coming through an API,

```
{
    "product":{
    "prodId": "PROD100"
    },
    "packages":{
    "pkgId": "PKG137"
    },
    "discount":"50",
    "periodFrom":null,
    "periodTo":null,
    "totalAmount": "599",
    "isActive": "false"
}
```

I have another small JSON, which I want to append at the top of it

```
"customer":{
    "custId":"CUST1002"
    },
```

**Final Structure:**

```
{
    "customer":{
    "custId":"1002"
    },
    "product":{
    "prodId": "PROD100"
    },
    "packages":{
    "pkgId": "PKG137"
    },
    "discount":"50",
    "periodFrom":null,
    "periodTo":null,
    "totalAmount": "599",
    "isActive": "false"
}
```

How do I achieve the same using `push` or `unshift`, or is there any best practice for the same in JavaScript or in typescript. Kindly suggest me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the object [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
const newJSON = { ...toAppend, ...original };
```

```js
const original = {
  "product": {
    "prodId": "PROD100"
  },
  "packages": {
    "pkgId": "PKG137"
  },
  "discount": "50",
  "periodFrom": null,
  "periodTo": null,
  "totalAmount": "599",
  "isActive": "false"
}


const toAppend = {
  "customer": {
    "custId": "CUST1002"
  },
}
const newJSON = { ...toAppend, ...original };
console.log(newJSON);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`spread-operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const obj = {
  "product": { "prodId": "PROD100" },
  "packages": { "pkgId": "PKG137" },
  "discount": "50",
  "periodFrom": null,
  "periodTo": null,
  "totalAmount": "599",
  "isActive": "false"
};
const toAdd = {
  "customer": { "custId":"CUST1002" }
};

const res = { ...toAdd, ...obj };

console.log(res);
```